# Can Powermockito mock final method in non-final concrete class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

Let's say I have a non-final concrete class with a final method like the one below.

```
public class ABC {
  public final String myMethod(){
      return "test test";
  }
}
```

is it possible to mock `myMethod()` to return something else when it is called in `junit` using `Powermockito`?  Thank you

Answer (score 32):

This works :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ABC.class)
public class ABCTest {

    @Test
    public void finalCouldBeMock() {
        final ABC abc = PowerMockito.mock(ABC.class);
        PowerMockito.when(abc.myMethod()).thenReturn("toto");
        assertEquals("toto", abc.myMethod());
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it is supposed to work but when I tried I always got exception below.  I'm wondering if I have set something wrong? `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/internal/MockitoInvocationHandler at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:138) at ABCTest.finalCouldBeMock(ABCTest.java:17) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @surawatthana You have to add Mockito in your classpath

Comment: Hi Gontard,   How dO I add Mockito in my classpath in Eclipse?

Comment: If you are using maven, look [here](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MavenUsers) else download [mockito.jar](http://mockito.googlecode.com/files/mockito-all-1.9.5-rc1.jar) then right click on your project -> Build path -> configure build path, librairies tab, add jar (select the downloaded library).

Comment: why do you guys always assume static imports are obvious? mentioning that you call PowerMockito.when(...) is quite helpful (even though given the question we can expect you are using PowerMockito)

Comment: Also, be sure you're statically importing `mock()` from `org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito` and not from `org.mockito.Mockito`.  My IDE automatically imported from the latter package, causing an error about not being able to mock final methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @PrepareForTest(Demo.class)
    public class DemoTest {

        @Rule
        public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule()

        @Before
        public void setup(){
        PowerMockAgent.initializeIfNeeded();
        }
        @Test
        public void finalClassMock() {
            final Demo demo = PowerMockito.mock(Demo.class);
            PowerMockito.when(demo.myMethod()).thenReturn("something");
            assertEquals("something", demo.myMethod());
        }
    }
```

or  this way also works thanks `@gontard`

Comment: Your comment is duplicated with the posted one.