# How to mock concrete class void method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock Lucenes `IndexReader.close()` to do nothing.

I thought this should work...

```
    IndexReader reader = Mockito.mock(IndexReader.class);
    Mockito.stubVoid(reader).toReturn().on().close(); // old approach
    Mockito.doNothing().when(reader).close(); // new approach
```

but both result in the unit test calling the actual, real close method and ultimately causing a null pointer exception.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#close%28%29) indicates, close() is a final method. And Mockito [can't mock final methods](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_limitations_of_Mockito).

Comment: :( O dear. Thanks JB. I don't suppose you have an idea how to get around without writing my own wrapper/interface?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139289/can-powermockito-mock-final-method-in-non-final-concrete-class could be the answer.