# Mock method call on internal mock object

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

I am writing a test case for my class which uses `KeyStore` to read certificate and key. I have mocked the `KeyStore` object and also tried to mock `KeyStore.getCertificate()` but this mocked method is not getting called. And am getting an error.

Below class represents my class to be tested

```
public class MyClass {
    public void methodToTest() {
        String keystoreFilename = "config/keystore.jks";
        String alias = "alise";
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
        KeyStore keystore = getKeyStore(keystoreFilename, password);
        Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
        Key key = keystore.getKey(alias, password);
    }

    public KeyStore getKeyStore(String keystoreFilename, char []password) throws KeyStoreException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        //TODO Cert and Key - remove this once able to get this from TA_DB APIs
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(keystoreFilename);
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keystore.load(fIn, password);
        return keystore;
    }
}
```

My Test case goes like this

```
@Test
public void testMethod() throws Exception{
    MyClass testClass = PowerMockito.mock(MyClass.class);
    //Mock certificate, key and KeyStore
    KeyStore keyStore = PowerMockito.mock(KeyStore.class);
    Certificate certificate = PowerMockito.mock(Certificate.class);
    Key key = PowerMockito.mock(Key.class);
    PowerMockito.when(keyStore.getCertificate(anyString())).thenReturn(certificate);
    PowerMockito.when(certificate.getEncoded()).thenReturn(TestConstants.RESPONSE_DATA);
    PowerMockito.when(keyStore.getKey(anyString(), anyObject())).thenReturn(key);
    PowerMockito.when(key.getEncoded()).thenReturn(TestConstants.RESPONSE_DATA);
    PowerMockito.when(testClass.getKeyStore(anyString(), any(char[].class))).thenReturn(keyStore);

    testClass.methodToTest();
}
```

But I am getting an error as

> Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitialized keystore at
>   java.security.KeyStore.getCertificate(KeyStore.java:1079) at
>   com.MyClass.methodToTest(MyClass.java:7)

Please notify me if am doing anything wrong or what is the exact way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Looks like mocking of the `KeyStore.getCertificate` method didn't work. Not an expert in Powermock, but maybe it's got something to do with that the 'getCertificate' method is final? Just a guess. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139289/can-powermockito-mock-final-method-in-non-final-concrete-class)  might help if this is the case.

Comment: Hi Jannis, your guess is correct and I tried the way mentioned in your suggested post. But still I am getting same error. I add a tag @PrepareForTest (KeyStore.class)